# Diagramming Decision Trees

Tags: algorithm, if-statement

I have been a self-taught coder for a long time, and I am asking for help with a conceptual problem here. I can solve this particular issue myself, but I feel like these problems always take me too long with trial & error solutions. I believe there is a way to Diagram this type of problem, but I don't know what it is called or how to look up this solution.

When I have multiple, often inter-dependent pre-conditions to a conditional outcome like as follows, it takes me forever to figure how to arrange my conditional statements:

I have a set of Values called: "Tab Numbers". Let's say I have 4 pre-conditions:

1. All Tab Numbers are blank
2. Some Tab Numbers are blank
3. A Session Boolean flag called SuppressPrompt is True
4. This Method is being called during the Open Session Event

These Pre-conditions determine my 3 desired outcomes:

A) Prompt for User Input
B) Auto-Populate Tab Numbers
C) Do Nothing

Now some of these pre-conditions affect other possible preconditions:

Eg.: The the Flag in Condition #3 cannot be set if the method is being called in the Open Method Condition #4.

I believe there is a good way to diagram these types of problems so that I don't have to puzzle through them with Trial & Error every time. Can anyone help point me to a resource to learn how to do this easier?

I am sorry if I am not posting this in the right place, but it is a problem that I keep running into. If anyone could just help point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It seems you are looking for a **truth table**.

Comment: Yes, but what do you call one with multiple inputs and inter-dependencies?

Comment: @gimix I do not know how to select your comment as an Answer. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What should happen if more than one of the four conditions are true?

Comment: @Stef, 
gimix did answer my question. What I was specifically trying to get at was a solution that if different multiple True values were input, they would produce different outputs. Some outputs may have multiple distinct combinations of True inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your truth table may look like this:

```
    Preconditions                                   Outcomes
AllBlank    SomeBlank   SupPrompt   OpenSession UserInput   AutoFill    Notes
T           T           [T]         T           ?           ?           Impossible
T           T           T           F           ?           ?
...
F           F           F           F           ?           ?
```

You will hopefully see some non obvious correlations, which will allow you to simplify your table, possibly splitting it, until you get the logical expression(s) you need

Comment: Do you have any references that I could use to read up more on this. So I can learn the Brace notation, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question. But I have had a similar problem recently.

Your may split your task into two truth tables - one for (A) and other for (B). Truth table can be represented as [Binary decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram). Binary decision tree can be further reduced to Binary decision diagram.
[image: BDD & BDT from wikipedia]

To create, reduce and visualize these structures use [CUDD](https://davidkebo.com/cudd). CUDD has ports and wrappers in many programming languages. For instance: DD (python), PAT BDD (.NET). CUDD can generate [DOT text for Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html).

With [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org) you can convert your diagrams to jpeg, png and a lot of other formats.